# Mysql connection with Visual C++

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2012, database-connection

I  have spent already 4 days trying to understand how to connect from  VS 2012. My program is written on C++,  it connects to Mysql  and insert in it records  from text file.  Problem: 1) I cant compile, it gives me linking mistakes:

1>DataTransformXYZtoDatabase.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_close@4
1>DataTransformXYZtoDatabase.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_query@8
1>DataTransformXYZtoDatabase.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_connect@32
1>DataTransformXYZtoDatabase.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4

So what I have done. I used staical library. My actions:

1. I created win32 console application in release mode
2. In Additional Include Directories added MySQL include/ catalog. (                C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include)
3. Link/General/Additional library directories / I wrote C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib\opt
4. Than Link/ input I wrote mysqlcppconn-static.lib и libmysql.lib.
5. C++/Preprocessor I wrote  CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC=
6. Also I added mysqlcppconn-static.lib и libmysql.lib to my exe file directory.

I included the following headers :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 
#include <boost\lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <windows.h>
//#include "my_global.h"
// MySQL connection
//#include <winSock2.h>
#include <winSock.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "libmysql.lib")
```

Please help me if you can. Thank you .

Comment: Search StackOverflow for MySql C++.  I have already answered a post that lists the libraries you need to link with.  You will want to change the project settings rather than using `#pragma comment`.

Answer (score 1):

I have also spent 2 days and here is the solution. Instead of console application I've used visual c++ app (the only difference is the defining the include and lib directories)

1. create application
2. add include directory (properties ->VC++ directories -> include directories)
3. add lib directory (properties ->VC++ directories -> library directories)
4. then properties->linker->input->additional dependencies -> libmysql.lib
5. copy a libmysql.dll (32bit) to the directory of the executable of your application

thats it! do not add any preprocessor commands or static libraries.